# Posting large files

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to upload large files with FileUpload control.
The page with this control located in Admin folder.

In admin folder's web.config file i set:

```
   <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="900000"/>
```

But this does not effect!

Only if I set this line in root's web.config it works.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a location section (in the web.config that is located in the root):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7(VS.71).aspx

Location - Path: The resource that the specified configuration settings apply to. Using location with a missing path attribute applies the configuration settings to the current directory and all child directories. If  is used with no path attribute and allowOverride is specified to be false, configuration settings cannot be altered by Web.config files in child directories.

The following example sets the uploaded file size limit to 128KB for only the page specified.

```
<configuration>
   <location path="UploadPage.aspx">
      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="128"/>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: can't believe I didn't think of this... I guess I've been at it too long. One up vote from me.

Comment: Where should I set it? in web.config that in admin folder?
When I set it to whole diectory it didn't work, so why should it work for a specific location?

Comment: or maybe I should use it in root web.config like:  <location path="Admin\UploadPage.aspx"> ?

Comment: Correct. In the root web.config

Answer (score 2):

the httpRuntime section is an application level setting, so it is not scoped to pages within a folder but to the entire application.

if you set the Admin area up as it's own application in IIS, this setting will work.

Comment: I try it in Visual Studio's server for now.

Comment: You can override it. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7(VS.71).aspx

Comment: DmitryK is correct. That's a much better solution than adding another Application in IIS as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IIS7, there's an [additional server change](http://weblogs.asp.net/steveschofield/archive/2007/05/11/iis7-post-40-adjusting-file-upload-size-in-iis7.aspx) you need to make to allow large file uploads at the server level. I wrote a post with [a lot of information about large file uploads in ASP.NET here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx).